# Script connection to other Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, attachment

I have a script in diferents objects to my boss. I program the script when the healt of boss is 10 or lower the speed to the other script is set to 4. I attach the first script to other script but dosen't work, the speed isn't change when the healt is low and i have no idea whats is the problem.

```
public int health = 12;
private gameMaster gm;
private UnityEngine.Object explosionRef;
public GameObject Hiedra;

public bool isHurt = false;

private HiedraScript ChangeVelocity;



void Start()
{
    gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameMaster").GetComponent<gameMaster>();
    explosionRef = Resources.Load("Explosion");
    ChangeVelocity = gameObject.GetComponent<HiedraScript>();
    
}

void Update()
{
    
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Bullet"))
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);

        health--;

        Hiedra.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Player_RedFlash");

        if (health <= 10)
            MovesFaster();
            isHurt = true;
            

        if (health <= 0)
            KillSelf();
    }
    if (health <= 0)
    {
        gm.points += 20;
    }
}

private void MovesFaster()
{
    ChangeVelocity.moveSpeed = 4f;
}
```

and the other value in diferent script:

```
public float moveSpeed = 1f;
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did you try to Debug.Log()?
If unity logging something so you have idea if it really calls MovesFaster() Function.

If so, you can mark **moveSpeed** variable as **static** and you can access it. I think this variable in a class inherited from monobehaviour. If you want to all public variable even that not static you can use ***singleton pattern***. Singleton pattern is so useful in many cases.

Comment: I used Debug.Log() and don't call the function MovesFaster().

Comment: Then problem isn't accessing another class. Problem looks like boss health never drops under 10. Boss's health is public, you should be able to see it in editor. Look for it. Maybe  there is problem on collision or something. Also as a fellow developer I encourage you to use Debug.Log() a lot in tests. It is really helpful quickfix tool.

Comment: Now it calls the function in Debug Log but show me this error:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
VitalPoint.MovesFaster () (at Assets/Script/Hiedra/VitalPoint.cs:58)
VitalPoint.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collision) (at Assets/Script/Hiedra/VitalPoint.cs:42)

Comment: Line 58 (Error line) is   **ChangeVelocity.moveSpeed = 4f;** this? If so you can't access that script. As I said before you can make it static or use singleton in that class.                                                                                     `public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static T instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = FindObjectOfType<T>();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: You just change class definition ( CLASS_NAME : Monobehaviour to CLASS_NAME : Singleton<CLASS_NAME>. Then you can access this classes public variable with CLASS_NAME.Instance.PUBLIC_VARIABLE

Comment: I change this to ChangeVelocity = GameObject.Find("Hiedra").GetComponent<HiedraScript>(); and works finally, but thanks for your answers.